# Why Would Requesting a Nonexistent Image Generate a 302 Response Instead of 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website and I have configured my main `.htaccess` file with this directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://websiteLink.com
```

When I access a page that has a link to a nonexistent image, instead of receiving a the 404 above, I receive a *302* response with the location directive that specified in the `.htaccess` configuration.

Why this 302 response generated?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the absolut url. You are using a full url in your ErrorDocument's destination. Use an absolute path

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/
```

Comment: i didn't understand how this redirection happened.i think the correct behaviour was that after redirecting to specified path in the error document and searches there for the image and not found , generate another 404 and go through infinite loop.

Comment: Your errorDocument is doing an external redirection of non-existent uris. When you request a non-existent file your ErrorDocument redirects it to a diffrent location using a 302 Temp Redirect status.